# A single word meaning doubt and unsettledness

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word suggesting doubt in the heart coupled with unsettledness?

One could doubt without being unsettled by an affair - I want a single word combining the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[*Qualm*](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-qualm.html) — "an uneasy feeling of doubt, worry, or fear; a misgiving".

Answer (score 3):

[trepidation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trepidation) is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Anxiety sounds like a good choice for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that but you could be anxious about something without doubting in it. 'I'm anxious about my job interview.' or doubt in something without being unsettled by it.'I doubt that I will come out this weekend.'

Comment: @nicholas: I disagree. Anxiety *is* the word you seek. You can't be *anxious* about something unless there's an element of doubt. If you *know* exactly what bad thing is going to happen, you're *fearful*, etc.

Comment: @FF, I disagree. Medications, and some mental conditions can cause anxiety with no external cause. A pretty lame technicality, but hey.

Comment: "Qualm" is an awesome word. I consider my suggestion checkmated.

Answer (score 2):

How about [*unease*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unease) or [*angst*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/angst)?

Comment: Bah. I came to post "unease" and you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @MrHen: Well, you're always getting in ahead of me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Perturbed*? According to NOAD:

> **perturb** *(verb)*
>   (often **be perturbed**) make (someone) anxious or unsettled